# Classe estacionamento em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes

Estou aprendendo a programar em Python.

Neste momento preciso de implementar uma class que tem as seguintes características:

Uma classe chamada estacionamento, que simula o funcionamento de um parque de estacionamento.

-A classe recebe um inteiro e determina a lotação do parque

-A classe devolve um objeto com os seguintes métodos:
Entra(): corresponde à entrada de um carro

-Sai(): corresponde à saída de um carro

-Lugares(): indica o número de lugares livres no estacionamento.

Estou com dificuldades em criar o codigo.

Não estou a conseguir fazer com que ***A classe recebe um inteiro e determina a lotação do parque***

[Codigo](https://repl.it/@jpfernandes/Classe-estacionamento)

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta pra incluir o que já tentou e onde não deu certo?

Comment: já coloquei lá o codigo. no entanto nao estou sendo capaz de fazer o input do inteiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua classe de controle estacionamento pode ser algo como:

```
class Estacionamento:

    def __init__( self, max_vagas ):
        self.max_vagas = max_vagas
        self.vagas_ocupadas = 0

    def maximo( self ):
        return self.max_vagas

    def disponiveis( self ):
        return self.max_vagas - self.vagas_ocupadas

    def ocupadas( self ):
        return self.vagas_ocupadas

    def entra( self ):
        if( self.vagas_ocupadas == self.max_vagas ):
            raise Exception('Estacionamento estah lotado!')
        self.vagas_ocupadas += 1

    def sai( self ):
        if( self.vagas_ocupadas == 0 ):
            raise Exception('Estacionamento estah vazio!')
        self.vagas_ocupadas -= 1
```

Testando:

```
n = int(input('Entre com a lotacao maxima do estacionamento: '))

e = Estacionamento(n)

e.entra()
e.entra()
e.entra()
e.entra()
e.sai()

print( e.maximo() )
print( e.disponiveis() )
print( e.ocupadas() )
```

Saída:

```
Entre com a lotacao maxima do estacionamento: 20
20
17
3
```

Comment: Ok!! muitoobrigado pela ajuda. Mas como faço para pedir ao utilizador um inteiro!?

Comment: Ou seja -A classe recebe um inteiro e determina a lotação do parque

Comment: Tente algo como: `n = int(input('Entre com a lotacao maxima do estacionamento: '))`

Comment: Consegui! Antes de declarar a class. mas não esta atualizar os lugares!

Comment: @JoaoPeixotoFernandes: feito!

Comment: muito obrigado pela disponibilidade e ajuda!! Funciona! obrigado